# InvalidOperationException on ShowDialog

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# application.

I have an object used like a dialog box :

```
public partial class MyDialog : Form
```

The main windows is :

```
public class MyForm : Form
```

I can use it by :

```
public class ProgramApp
{
    public static MyForm MainForm { get { return _mainForm;  } }
}
```

In one function I can use both with :

```
MyDialog dlg = new MyDialog();
dlg.ShowDialog(ProgramApp.MainForm);
```

First call works good, but at the second one I have a System.InvalidOperationException with HResult = 0x80131509 and message :

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MainForm' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

(translated from french, original message :)

> "Opération inter-threads non valide : le contrôle 'MainForm' a
>   fait l'objet d'un accès à partir d'un thread autre que celui sur
>   lequel il a été créé."

What can I do to fix that ?

Edit :

I added this piece of code :

```
MyDialog dlg = new MyDialog();
bool needInvokeDlg = dlg.InvokeRequired;
bool needInvokeForm = ProgramApp.MainForm.InvokeRequired;
dlg.ShowDialog(ProgramApp.MainForm);
```

First attempt both are false. On second, needInvokeForm is true. How can I do an Invoke to set ProgramApp.MainForm as a parameter ?

Comment: did not find an answer on the original post

Comment: @dotctor Can you re-open the question please ?

Comment: Perhaps it would be enough to just cast the form to the required `IWin32Window` interface,  i.e. `dlg.ShowDialog((IWin32Window)ProgramApp.MainForm);` as that doesn't have any UI element.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. The problem for me is to give the `MainForm` as parameter in another thread. I've try to invoke from `MainForm` and `dlg` but nothing works. I need help and my question has been closed (2 minutes after asking, I wonder if the closer read the question). Anyway i'll try an other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog needs to be invoked on the UI thread.

For a thorough discussion, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the/19023209#19023209).